# Handling change event for pagination in dojo gridx

Tags: javascript, pagination, dojo.gridx

I am using dojo gridx1.3.
My application has much data so I use the pagination (multiple pages) in the gridx.

I am trying to handle the change page events and highlight a particular text changing color.

1.Handle the page changed event.
2.Check the each value in all cells.
3.Change text color if match the condition.

Following sample can realize my requirement.
Is there any efficient way to handle the page change event and change the color of text.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.onload = function () {
  function setColorFunc() {
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("gridxBody")[0].getElementsByTagName("td");
    var chktxt, sp;

    for(var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
      chktxt = ele[i].textContent;
      sp = Number(chktxt.split("-")[1]);
      if(sp % 3 == 0) {
        ele[i].classList.add("colorRed");
      }
    }
  }

  var tableBody = document.getElementsByClassName("gridxBody")[0];

  tableBody.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", setColorFunc);

};
//]]>
</script>
```

I heard that DOMSubtreeModified to be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the how to handle the page change event in dojo.gridx pagination.
pagination.onSwitchPage can handle the event.
Please refer the following code.

```
require([
    'dojo/parser',
    'gridx/tests/support/data/MusicData',
    'gridx/tests/support/stores/Memory',
    'gridx/Grid',
    'gridx/core/model/cache/Sync',
    'gridx/allModules',
    'dojo/domReady!'
], function(parser, dataSource, storeFactory){

    store = storeFactory({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        size: 100
    });

    layout = dataSource.layouts[7];

    first = function(){
        grid1.pagination.gotoPage(0);
    };
    last = function(){
        grid1.pagination.gotoPage(grid1.pagination.pageSize() - 1);
    };
    prev = function(){
        grid1.pagination.gotoPage(grid1.pagination.currentPage() - 1);
    };
    next = function(){
        grid1.pagination.gotoPage(grid1.pagination.currentPage() + 1);
    };

    parser.parse();

    orgEv = grid2.pagination.onSwitchPage;
    grid2.pagination.onSwitchPage = function() {
        orgEv();
        alert("switchPage");
    };
});
```